# How can I kill the Mirelurk Queen?

Tags: fallout-4

I just encountered the Mirelurk Queen, and she kicked my ass pretty thoroughly. I'm at level 17, and I really didn't expect a level 50 boss to appear in this mission. Everthing before went very well, I didn't have any issues with the regular Mirelurks before the queen appears.

One issue is that the queen does a lot of damage if she hits me, apart from evading better is there anything I can do to reduce that damage?

What are the weaknesses of the queen? I didn't have any weapons with me that could do more than chip off more than a tiny bit of health with each shot.

Any particular strategies that work against this enemy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first time I tried this was on Normal difficulty. I died the first time. The second time I only used  a couple stimpacks.

**The most important thing is to be inside when the queen is attacking.** You can easily dodge her ranged poison attack from there. You can also fight any babies that come your way without worrying about the queen. It also helps to **lay down mines** on the break in the wall where she comes in. Just like with any other boss chems can be useful, especially Psycho.

Inside the walls, there is a **missile launcher**, along with some missiles. I can't recall exactly how many, but I think it was at least seven scattered about. Pick those up. There's also a flamer and a decent amount of flamer fuel, but I didn't want to get that close to her. The flamer might work well on the babies.

From inside, I stood in the doors and shot missiles at her. You don't need to use VATS for this, even if you normally use it for all your shots. Just aim at the lower part of her body, under the shell, and fire. Whenever she looked my way, I ran to another door and avoided the ranged attack. It leaves some **harmful mist** behind, so **don't run right back into it**. This attack does poison damage, which ignores your ballistic and energy resistances. You can get poison resistance from the "Poisoner's" [legendary armor effect](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_armor_effects), and also from Astoundingly Awesome Tales #5: The Mad Russian's Revenge, which can be found in [Pickman Gallery](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pickman_Gallery).

That character wasn't that good at combat, but after firing all the missiles I was able to finish the queen off with some combat rifle shots.

I've since defeated the queen on Hard, Very Hard, and Survival. This basic strategy continues to work, although you're going to need more missiles. In future playthroughs, I've saved all the missiles I've run into, rather than selling them. This gives me dozens by the time I get to the castle.

If you can do good ranged damage, especially if you can do a lot of crits, you might be able to kill her easily enough with your regular gun. **The queen's head is weak**, just like other mirelurks. If you can't hit the head, the rest of her body is still weaker than the shell. If you have Macready's perk, Killshot, then hitting her head is extremely easy, and the whole fight shouldn't be too much trouble.

Comment: The missile launcher in combination with some Psycho did the trick. Staying inside is also mandatory as you said.

Comment: Used mostly the same tactics and successfully defeated it on Survival lvl 20. The KEY to success is to completely avoid all the acid spits (they are one shot kill for you on that difficulty and there is absolutely no means to recover). I've dealt most damage via my stored critical hits from tuned Overseer's Guardian, although I died like 10 times trying to accomplish (that's definitely the toughest challenge on my Survival so far, all previous "Oh F*" situations where bypassed via Jet.

Comment: This has some useful advice, but is very focused on 1 spawn location (and the question doesn't seem to mention a location, not that that should change things much though). You may want to generalize this given that the queen can spawn in (at least?) 9 locations (according to the Wiki). All the other answers also seem to have this problem.

Comment: @NotThatGuy This question is about the mission at the castle. From the question body: "really didn't expect a level 50 boss to appear in this mission". I'm not sure we were aware that that type of enemy appeared outside the mission at the time it was asked. All the advice not directly related to the missile launcher applies to other queens as well.

Comment: Assuming you used some mines, it might be worth VATS-targeting her feet/legs to see if any are close to being crippled. If you can cripple her ability to walk effectively you'll find it easier to kite her. Likewise with her head, although a bit harder: if you cripple it, her accuracy with the poison shot goes down.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [mines can be useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwFSv.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

The Mirelurk Queen doesn't spawn until you've smashed ~6 full groups of eggs.

You can abuse this somewhat by seeding the fallen wall area that she comes through with Mines.

There is also, as noted in other answers, a flamethrower and missile launcher stashed within the building.

Personally, I used mines, a single fat-boy shell, the missile launcher *and* the minigun.

Answer (score 3):

Killed her as a lvl 8 sniper spec. I shot her in the face with a scoped rifle while hidden, then ran around to the left side of the fort to lose aggro. Repeated the process 10 times and she was dead.

I really hate taking advantage of the mechanics like that, but she was stomping me otherwise. I probably wouldn't have started the Fort mission if i knew there would be an lvl 50 MMO style boss at the of it.

Answer (score -1):

Well I just did that question and I'm lvl 15. I basically took the necessary chems and got far enough to where she was focused in everybody else,  tho I only made it with one surviving minuteman, and just kept chipping away. Use every grenade u have and fire seems to work well. Molotov and I luckily had an incendiary laser pistol. But pretty much used every once of ammo I had man. Just keep your distance. Don't use melee. Run. And let the others distract and light her up. Also go for anything but the outer shell hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I did it with the minigun, still had around 1300 bullets, so just stand in the wall, and shoot a party (level 8 btw)

Answer (score -3):

If you can get her and your NPCs outside she focuses on them, leaving you to snipe rather comfortably from the high walls. You don't even have to bother to be honest, as they constantly cause damage and she should ignore you.